# Why am I getting "Unauthorized" when calling Kubernetes api from pod?

Tags: kubernetes

From a pod, I'm trying to get information about a service, using the kubernetes api. Up until a couple of weeks ago, it was working just fine. I'm not sure what changed. Here's the code I'm using:

```
SERVICE_NAME="rabbitmq"
KUBE_TOKEN=`cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`
KUBE_BASE_API_URL="https://${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}:${KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT}/api/v1/namespaces/${KUBERNETES_POD_NAMESPACE}"
KUBE_AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN"
SERVICE_INFO=$(/usr/bin/curl -sSk -H "${KUBE_AUTH_HEADER}" "$KUBE_BASE_API_URL/endpoints/$SERVICE_NAME")
```

I'm populating the `KUBERNETES_POD_NAMESPACE` environment variable using the downward api. The value of `SERVICE_INFO` is `Unauthorized`

I don't know if it's related or not, but i noticed when I tried to ping `https://kubernetes`, I get `ping: unknown host https://kubernetes`. However, I believe kube-dns is running just fine, because it looks up `http://rabbitmq` just fine.

I'm on Kubernetes v1.1.1, and I'm using local machines that are running CoreOS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix it, I wound up having to recreate the master. I'm still not sure exactly what happened